# Piping HAProxy log parser and Zabbix_sender

Tags: pipe, haproxy, zabbix

It seems like I need an advice on how to parse HAProxy logs and send them into Zabbix.
Below are two scripts which work fine, and I need them to work all together as one-line script.

Command to get query processing time from haproxy logs in real time:

```
tail -f haproxy.log | awk '{print $10}' | cut -d/ -f4
```

Command to send one value into zabbix.

```
echo "- haproxy.app.processing.time 1234"|zabbix_sender --config /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf --input-file - -vv
```

I suppose it should be some trick with pipes there to link them together, and that is where I need help. Please advice.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `cut` at the end of the first line and `echo` at the beginning of the second with `awk`, and then join the two lines together, like so:

```
... | awk -F/ '{ print "- haproxy.app.processing.time", $4 }' | ...
```

You might also wish to consider using `-F` option to `tail`, so that the command does not stop when the log file rotates, and also `--real-time` option to `zabbix_sender`, so that it sends data as soon as it is received, rather than wait for a  bunch of values to pile up.

Comment: I found the following solution  

    `tail -f haproxy.log | awk '{print $10}' | cut -d/ -f4 | while read VALUE; do echo "- haproxy.app.processing.time $VALUE" | zabbix_sender --config /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf --real-time --input-file -; done`  
  
Tried to use yours, but it returned an error:  
    `tail -f haproxy.log | awk -F/ '{ print "- haproxy.app.processing.time", $4 }' | zabbix_sender --config /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf --real-time --input-file - -vv`

Comment: @Max: In my solution, you might have missed "awk '{print $10 }'". With that part in place, what error do you get?